# Ну почему мне никто не сказал, что перед освоением framework надо хотя бы почитать про паттерны?

Tags: php, фреймворк

Впервые с понятием фреймворка познакомился раньше, чем с понятием шаблона проектирования, поэтому возникало множество неясностей по поводу работы первого. Теперь, когда знаком и с тем, и с другим, логика работы некоторых фреймворков мне стала более понятна. Это как недостающая часть мозаики в знаниях... Возможно, есть еще что-то в области программирования, с чем я еще не знаком, но стоило бы знать при освоении фреймворка и анализе чужого кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут я думаю проблема разработчиков.
Возьмем к примеру Laravel там одна из первых статей на сайте русского сообщества [Введение в архитектуру и паттерны программирования](http://laravel.ru/articles/devpilgrim/patterns-intro)  а в документации соответственно описание классов и методов так как и должно быть. Хотите разбираться с нуля читайте не только документацию а и статьи если считаете что готовы то вам и документации достаточно будет или просто код фреймворка посмотреть.

Comment: Теперь чаще ловлю себя на мысли, что мне все-таки проще будет код смотреть, документация хорошая встречается далеко не часто, да еще и на русском (хотя, это конечно, не проблема, но для меня процесс пока тормозит), а если и находится, то часто не совпадает или(и) не полностью описывает возможности кода... Думаю вы меня поняли )))

Спасибо за ссылку, очень интересный материал.

Answer (score 1):

Нормальное развитие разработчика, если что то встречаешь неведомое, то нужно раскапывать самому, а то не поймёшь зачем эти странные паттерны, с чем их едят. Я думаю, у разработчика на ПХП первый шаблон проектирования - синглтон. Уже понял почему? ;)
Вообщем грабли нужно собрать, это и есть опыт, хоть и первоначальный.

Comment: Синглтон - пожалуй, самый первый с которым я познакомился (в CodeIgniter, хотя тогда еще и не знал, что это паттерн). Cогласен, потому что считаю, что он универсален а в комбинации с другими паттернами можно писать код настолько гибкий, насколько это нужно, т.е. в такой связке отпадают архитектурные ограничения.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется значение *шаблонов проектирования* сейчас сильно преувеличивают. Шаблоны это типовые решения для типовых ситуаций. Да, их полезно знать. Хотябы для того, чтобы успешно общаться в профессиональной среде. Но даже если не знаешь названия, ты всё равно их используешь :)

Это примерно как: когда быстро бежишь — сильно топаешь и усиленно дышишь. Поведенческий шаблон. Но если, эм… молиться на шаблоны, то получится так: «если хочешь быстро бежать — пыхти и топай!»